# Okhttp: get cookie from Set-cookie header in a series of redirects

Tags: android, redirect, cookies, okhttp

I can use `OkhttpClient` to send a `GET` request to the server and get the cookie in the final response properly(the response code of which is 200 )and the cookie of which can be retrieved using `addInterceptor()`.

Request-> 302(Set-cookie`?`) -> 302(Set-cookie`?`) -> 302(Set-cookie`?`) ->200(Set-cookie√(can be get using interceptor))

(the question mark `?` means don't know how to get)

But the situation here is that there might be a series of redirects before the final response(200) is returned, the redirects carry the `Set-cookie` header. Is there any way using `Okhttp` to retrieve the cookies in the `Set-cookie` header in every `redirect`?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: @iOSAddicted sorry no. I used another way to solve the problem. I have a thought with practise that I can use ``followRedirect(false)`` method to stop each redirect by adding the method to several ``OkhttpClient``s,those clients share the same ``CookieJar``.

Comment: @iOSAddicted BTW, I posted the question mainly because I came across the ``too many follow-up`` exception. I successfully dealt with the exception by implementing ``loadForRequest()`` matching different urls with their cookies in the request header.